# Which one is better for Ubuntu? ARM or Intel?

Tags: boot, intel, arm

If i was going to buy a new laptop or pc which would be better if i would only install Ubuntu?

I've read some articles about Ubuntu booting really fast with ARM and on their new 12.04 they promised 2seconds boot time.

which would be better if i was only looking forward to fast loading like opening apps and booting and shut down fast?

Comment: Different Architectures, different results, simply opening apps fast and shutting down fast is *not* a reason to choose a platform over the other.

Comment: this depends on a million different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looking for optimization for speed, that will go more likely to the hard drive. Hard drives are tipically sorted on two actual general options. 5400RPM hard drives are cheaper, and generally you get laptops with that. (Watch out since you may pay lots of $$ for a big sized hdd with slow speed.)

7200RPM hard drives have a better speed, but they've a more expensive price.
SSD drives are something totally different. SSDs make your boot amazingly faster, (watch some youtube videos of comparisons). SSDs are very reliable, make no-noise. However, SSDs are way too expensive, and they usually sort small capacity drives.

You should check what are your needs in order to know what kind of drive you need.

On the other hand, ARM processors have some architectural limits, as far as I know, Ubuntu on ARM will not let you get flash-video and other vital stuff. Still ARM is a very hard-to-warm processor. That's why tablets don't have fans, like laptops.
As for today, Windows 7 will not run on any ARM processor. (Win8 is supposed to do so.)

Common processor architectures, (x86, for 32-bit, x64, for 64-bit) are the tipical and most recommended choices. They are compatible for anything in general. Also they are SUPPOSED to be faster, (might as well be that ARM processors usually have low clock speeds). I recommend you getting a x64 processor, either from AMD or INTEL.

If you need anything except hardcore gaming, go INTEL, they architecture is proven to be a little step ahead to AMD's. However, AMD's crossfire technology (make the AMD processor work hand to hand with a ATI graphics chipset) is something to considerate).

If you do worry about heating, AMD's brand new APU (combination of graphics card and processor into a single chipset) is really great at keeping things cool.

But you now, over every actual processor, (Intel Core i' series or AMD A' series), most speed for opening things comes more from the hard drive on your system.

I know it may be confusing, but I just tried to explain everything so you can go for your best choice. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

ARM is only for mobile devices (I think). I'm using AMD A6, and it's great. Intel Core i3 is very fast too (and of course, i5 and i7 are even faster). It depends on your budget :)

Comment: Yes ARM is for Mobile devices, as of now. And there are no Laptops or Desktops with ARM SoC available that match the performance of an i5,7,3 or an AMD AX CPUs.

Comment: Or the AMD FX CPUs (first CPU series to have 8-core)!

Comment: or a Core2Duo even..

Answer (score 0):

Intel x86 and x64 are almost universally faster than ARM.  This is not necessarily in clock, but in general 'goodies' you get along side.  ARM based solutions usually have 1 GB or less in ram and lower clock.  You'll also get a lot more stable packages in x86 or x64.  ARM support is lacking in a lot of areas.  It boots and runs, but it's not there yet.